# SDL Web 8.5: GetListFavorites/GetListSystemAdministration could not be activated

Tags: core-service, cme, gui-extensions, web8.5

Recently I Installed SDL Web 8.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2. After Installation, when I opened the CME I got below notification error. I am facing this issue only on one server and other server is working fine with SDL Web 8.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2. I think it's an environment configuration issue.

[image]

> The requested service,
>   'http://localhost:12300/WebUI/Models/CME/Services/General.svc/GetListSystemAdministration'
>   could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Communicator.ProcessWebServiceCall(Object state)

[image]

> The requested service,
>   'http://localhost:12300/WebUI/Models/CME/Services/General.svc/GetListFavorites'
>   could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Communicator.ProcessWebServiceCall(Object state)

Comment: Check the event log for *warnings* from *ASP.NET*. There's usually more information there about why the service could not be activated.

Comment: You have tagged the question with [tag:gui-extensions], is that because you have a UI extension installed, if so, does it work when you disable/remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**It`s working fine after removed the below highlighted line in Web.config**
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Was this an upgrade or new install and was the extra endpoint node there intentionally?

Comment: this is a change SDL made in SDL Web 8.5 (check -> checker). we had been adding HTTPS stuff for a long time, since when we first installed many years ago, there was no HTTPS enable script in those days. and, since we were upgrading from 2013 sp1 to web 8.5, the upgrader didn't modify things... so it still worked.

however, for clean installs (not upgrades) when we run the HTTPS enable ps script, it adds entry with "check" and then our MSI adds entry for "checker" (or vice versa, I forget) so we have double entry and it's invalid.

Comment: also... this one of those unfortunate things related to upgrades... would be nice to have list of "here's what changed in this release" like many other vendors provide--then we would have known this one right away. :)

Comment: Faced this issue when we do a mixed mode upgrade in Win2k8 servers. Solved our problem! Thanks.